# Debian ignores PAM env variables (while Arch doesn't)

Tags: debian, environment-variables, pam

I have a weird issue with my Debian Sid system. I want to set a global environment variable in `/etc/environment`, which is supposed to be read by the `pam_env` module. Unfortunately, after having relogin in the system, the variable is not set.

On another Arch Linux box, the same variable set in `etc/environment` is defined as expected.
Just for testing, I tried to setup a local env variable in `.pam_environment` and, again, on Debian it's not being defined while on Arch it is.

I'm using GDM on Debian and SDDM on Arch as login managers.
What am I missing? Which (PAM or GDM) configuration files should I look at?

EDIT: 
output of `grep pam_env /etc/pam.d/*`

```
$ grep pam_env /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/atd:auth     required        pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/cron:# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
/etc/pam.d/cron:# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/cron:session       required   pam_env.so
/etc/pam.d/cron:session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/gdm-autologin:session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/gdm-autologin:session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/gdm-launch-environment:session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/gdm-launch-environment:session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/gdm-password:session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/gdm-password:session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/login:# file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/login:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/login:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
/etc/pam.d/polkit-1:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
/etc/pam.d/polkit-1:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
/etc/pam.d/su:# file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
/etc/pam.d/su:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
/etc/pam.d/su:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/664236/257378

Comment: @goldilocks See the updated answer for the output of `grep -l pam_env /etc/pam.d/*`

Comment: Have a look at `man pam_env` and `man pam.d`.  I don't know the answer here, but that's where I'd start investigating -- I notice not everything in pam.d references the pam_env modules.

Comment: Remove the `-l` from your grep command, the `pam_env` module needs `readenv=1` to process the `/etc/environment` file. Your grep output now doesn't tell whether that's enabled or not.

Comment: @wurtel Done, check the updated question.

Comment: Does it work if you use `ssh` to login to your system? Otherwise it all looks fine so I have no idea why it's not working for you. No messages appearing in some syslog file when you login that could indicate an error somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: if, on Debian, you add

```
session required        pam_env.so user_readenv=1
```

to `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` then PAM will indeed apply your env var settings in `~/.pam_environment` when you do a password login using GDM.  If you log in using something else then look for the corresponding file under `/etc/pam.d`.

Comment: That to common session works for a gdm3 gnome login. It doesnt (there or gdb-password) on debian bullseye logging into default xsession (calling i3) via gdm.  What a right royal mess. The whole startup thing too. For those that deny it, just Google the issues..